# Element with overflow-y changes width in a flexbox parent container

Tags: css

The problem is best seen in this **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4q6a7axb/)**. A child div (defined by class `.description` stretches several inches beyond its parent container when a long string is typed into it. I have broken my head to figure out the reason. Help me please.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/4q6a7axb/1/

```
Adding a overflow and width attribute to the .description class seemed to do justice!
```

Comment: The problem arises in case of **continuous** long strings. See this http://jsfiddle.net/fwf30bxf/